# Use PyQGIS to import CSV and draw points using different color

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-2, python-2.7

A CSV file contains columns `latitude`, `longitude` and `color`.

```
uri = "file:///C:/data/balls.csv?type=csv&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Balls', "delimitedtext")
```

Using the Python console in QGIS, how can we draw each row in the CSV as a point whose color depends on the value in the `color` column of the imported CSV?

It's my understanding that `QgsDataSourceURI.setDataSource()` can do such a WHERE query during the import, but only works on PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you should access to data defined properties for the symbol layer and set the color by passing the field name as expression. You can do it like:

```py
uri = "file:///C:/data/balls.csv?type=csv&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Balls', "delimitedtext")

mySymbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(vlayer.geometryType())
mySymbolLayer = mySymbol.symbolLayer(0)
## replace COLOR_FIELD with the column name of your CSV data
mySymbolLayer.setDataDefinedProperty("color", '"COLOR_FIELD"')
vlayer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, mySymbolLayer)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```