# How to import CSV layer to QGIS using PyQGIS in Windows?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv

I'm using QGIS 2.18.14 Las Palmas on Windows 8.1
I tried to import CSV layer to QGIS using this script:

```
uri = 'file://D:/26mei.csv?d?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s' % (",", "Lon", "Lat")
layer_csv = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'paramHilal', 'delimitedtext')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer_csv)
```

The last line is to add the CSV layer to layer panel in QGIS, but it didn't appear. It could be because the layer is not valid.
I knew because I have tried `layer_csv.isValid()` and it return `False`. But I don't know where my mistake is.
Does anyone knows why my script is not work?

PS: I have tried this on QGIS 2.8 Wien on Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a tip according to this:
[Use PyQGIS to import CSV and draw points using different color](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120149/use-pyqgis-to-import-csv-and-draw-points-using-different-color)

use `///` instead `//` after `file`.

Comment: It's working, there is a typo in the cookbook in the description but in the example it uses triple slash `///` then I thought double slash `//` makes more sense since URL in web browser also uses `//`